# Why is this program in C crashing?

Tags: c, image-processing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "imageio.h"
#include "imageio.c"

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    IMAGE image = loadImage("test.bmp");
    printf("Enter the number of pixels in the x axis: ");
    scanf("%d", &image.width);
    printf("Enter the number of pixels in the y axis: ");
    scanf("%d", &image.height);
    for (i=0;i<image.width; i++)
      for (j=0;j<image.height; j++){
            RGB pixel = image.pixels[i][j];
            pixel.R = pixel.R * 0.299;
            pixel.G = pixel.G * 0.587;
            pixel.B = pixel.B * 0.114;
            image.pixels[i][j] = pixel;
      }
    saveImage("modified_test.bmp", image);
}
```

saveImage,loadImage and struct RGB have been defined in the header files. The objective is to turn an image into greyscale

Comment: where is `saveImage` function? Have you checked all conditions? like what if `loadImage` fail?

Comment: `Why is this program in C crashing?` -- Where, how, what's the error?

Comment: Why do you input the size? The BMP image already has a size, I would expect `image.width` and `image.height` to be set to the proper values after loading. Very strange.

Comment: @Jayesh it is in one of the includes (it definately works fine)

Comment: @devnull I don't know what the problem is

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? It will stop where the crash happens, allowing you to see and walk up the function call stack.

Comment: A major problem fur us is that we don't know what `image.pixels` is. Please edit the question to show at least this structure.

Comment: I don't know what library you're using, but `pixels[i][j]` looks weird. Usually, and image is an array of rows, so the major index should be `j`, not `i`. Does it still crash when you swap height and width?

Comment: Also, if you want a greyscale image, you should set R,G and B to the same value. Right now, you're multiplying each channel with a factor, but they still have different values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (i=0;i<image.width; i++)
    for (j=0;i<image.height; j++){
    //       i ???
```

Do you mean `j < image.height`?

Comment: Not in the code as you posted it. The second loop assigns to `j` but tests for `i`